# Vue.js - how toggle icon class on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

Here's a snippet of my code in which on page load my div is collapsed and the icon initial class is set to 'fa fa-chevron-up'. How do I toggle the icon's class to 'fa fa-chevron-down' when a is clicked?

```js
var vue = new Vue({
 el: '#vue-systemActivity',
 data: {
    loading:false, 
    collapsed: true
  }
  
});
```

```css
.is-collapsed{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<a v-on:click=" collapsed = !collapsed" class="collapse-link"> 
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [:class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Array-Syntax):

```
<i :class="[collapsed ? 'fa-chevron-up' : 'fa-chevron-down', 'fa']"
```